# Transferring a data from a mongodb on my local machine to a docker container

Tags: database, mongodb, docker, nosql, database-migration

I'm trying to deploy a site and I am stuck trying to get my MongoDB data into my docker container. My API seems to work just fine without the docker container but when it is run using the docker container, it throws an error. The errors are due to the database being empty. I'm looking for a way to transfer previously stored data from my local MongoDB to the MongoDB on my container. Any solutions for this.
Below is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
    - "3030:3030"
    depends_on:
    - mongo
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
    - "27018:27017"
```

I was told using mongodump and mongorestore could be helpful but haven't had much luck with mongorestore.

Currently, I have a dump folder with the db that I'm trying to transfer on my local machine. What steps should I take next to get it into docker?

Comment: could you explain the issue with your mongorestore ? maybe you can use COPY in your Dockerfile and then run mongodb restore script using CMD

Comment: @protrafree That's what I'm attempting to now. I was trying to do it all in one step but I just copied my dump over into my container. Now I'm just trying to figure out where to mongorestore within my docker container.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue for anyone attempting to populate their mongo database in docker.

Here are the steps I took:

First used the mongodump to copy my database into a dump file
mongodump --db

Used docker cp to copy that dump file into a docker container
docker cp ~/dump/ :/usr/

Used mongorestore inside of the docker container
Open docker mongo shell in Docker Desktop or docker exec -it  bash

cd into the usr directory
mongorestore --db= --collection= ./dump//.bson